# Navigating the results of vimgrep in listform (clist)?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to view vimgrep results in a nice list format .. and quickly go through each result?

I though it was change list  / clist but this only seems to list files without letting me go to each.

I know there are two list "buffers" in vim but I forgot how they work and how I can use them to do what I want.

Thanks

Note: I also know I can use `:cnext` `:cprev`

Answer (score 3):

I now see the answer is to use QuickFix

With the :cope ex command. and then pressing enter on any file.

The other change list and jump list concepts I had in mind turn out to be helpful for viewing history in various forms.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
     :clist
```

Your answer says you don't want just a list, though?  I'm a bit confused by what you're looking for.

You could set up a mapping to take you to the next change with a keystroke.
For example, to make the key sequence (space, m) take you to the next result you could do this:

```
     :noremap <Space>n :cnext<C-m>
     :noremap <Space>p :cprev<C-m>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Quickfix window that you can use to display and act upon an "error list" or a "location list".

After you have done `:vim foo %`, use the `:cw[indow]` command to display the "error list" *if there is a match.*

This is how you would search for `$foo` in a whole PHP project and display the results, in one command:

```
:vim /$foo/ **/*.php | cw
```